# check if one item of radio button checked

Tags: jquery, html

i have some radio buttons :

```
<input type="radio" id="rdoLevel" name="rdoSelect" />
<input type="radio" id="rdoBase" name="rdoSelect" />
<input type="radio" id="rdoSchool" name="rdoSelect" />
<input type="radio" id="rdoTypeRegistre" name="rdoSelect" />
```

and i want to check each item by id,for example i want to check if rdoLevel equal checked some code perform
for example like this :

```
 $("input:radio").click(function () {
                    var id = $(this).attr("id");
                    if (id == "rdoLevel") {
                        //some code
                    }
                });
```

how can i do this?
**thanks in your advise!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $("input:radio").click(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                if (id == "rdoLevel" && $(this).is(':checked')) {
                    //some code
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("input[name='rdoSelect']").change(function() {
    switch (this.id) {
        case "rdoLevel":
            // ...
            break;
        case "rdoBase":
            // ...
            break;
        // etc
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/kQC9L/

Answer (score 1):

Change your click to the following. (The type selector was incorrect.)

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);

});​
```